# How switch between two different datepickers and select one to display based on a condition?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a navigation bar component that has some drop downs and a datepicker. All from angular-material.

Now, i want to change the type of date picker being displayed in this component based on the page being displayed. Some pages require a date picker that takes in dates, while some ask for a date picker where we can only select week of a month.

How to do this without breaking the dynamic nature of the application?

I am new to Angular and material both. Tried a few silly things but didnt work

Comment: Hmm.. what have you tried so far? There are many ways to approach this. You can either conditionally render the datepickers, or conditionally set the input property bindings for the datepicker.

Comment: Tried <p *ngIf="method()"> with #name on each date picker.
Also tried <ng-content>, but thats a whole different concept i reckon.

Comment: sounds like you try to run before you can walk. you should start with angular's  [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial#tour-of-heroes-app-and-tutorial)

Comment: I would and am. The work demands should also be meet with regard to time. Thanks for the reference by the way. I would equally appreciate a solution.

Comment: @Shashanksarma Maybe you can try posting your code here? Or reproduce the issue on Stackblitz so that we have a demo to work on?